# Processingでのthisの受け取りについて

Tags: java, tcp, processing

現在TCP通信を行おうとして、Class側で初期化したいのですが
thisの受け取り方がわからずできません

void setupではなく、コンストラクタ側でserver = new Server(this, 3333);
で初期化したい

詳しく教えてもらえると助かります。

追記
解決しました！

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの質問ですが、もっと具体的な状況を知りたいので、コードの断片か、参考にしているサイト・書籍などの情報を本文に直接追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記することができます。

Comment: `setup()`ではなくコンストラクタで初期化したい何か特別な理由があるのでしょうか？その理由を**質問本文を編集して**追記された方がより良い回答がつくかもしれません。Processingに詳しくなくて申し訳ないのですが、初期化処理は通常`setup()`内で行うかと思います。https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Server.html

Comment: classを呼び出した時にコンストラクタ側で初期化したほうがきれかなと思ったのでしつもんさせていだだきました。ですがもう解決しました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: @フォルテ さん、お疲れ様です。もし宜しければ、どのように解決なさったのか回答として投稿して頂ければ幸いです。自己解決したときに[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することは推奨されています :)